# Reading text files in python

Tags: python, file

```
endofprogram=False 
try:
    filename=input("Enter filename: ")
    infile=open(filename,"r")
except IOError:
    print("Error reading file! Program ends here!")
    endofprogram=True
if endofprogram==False:
    highest=0.0
    for line in infile:
        line=line.strip('\n')
        if(line!="") and (line[0]!='#'):
            name,grade=line.split('\t')
            if(float(grade)>highest):
                highest=float(grade)

                hname=name
        record=(hname,highest)

        print(record)
        infile.close()
```

We're working on files in comp sci now. This program is supposed to find the highest grade in a certain .txt file that I named "File1.txt".

```
#fname lname grade
Charlie Watson  8
Alice Brown     8.5
#Comments

Francene Walk   9
Robert Wilson   7
Evelyn Stewart  10
Gordon Rogers   8.5
```

So in order to access this file through the program we're supposed to have it in the same folder, as we were taught in class. But when I enter the correct file name as an input through the program I get the "Error reading file!" message displayed. Is this because I'm using a Mac and there's a different method to reading files through python on OSX?

Comment: Are you sure you typed in the correct file name? Does your program throw an exception if you do `infile = open("File1.txt")`

Comment: "Is this because I'm using a Mac and there's a different method to reading files through python on OSX?" — No and no.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's the correct file name. From what I was told, as long as the program and the .txt file are in the same folder it should work.

Answer (score 0):

if it's Python 2, you probably want `raw_input` not `input`.

as a general rule, when developing a program it's a good idea, at the end of your `except` clause, to use `raise`. this throws the original exception and shows you better what went wrong.

Comment: `input()` might be OK, depends on which version of Python he's using.